# Two NSArrayControllers on one NSManagedObjectContext?

Tags: macos, cocoa, core-data, nsarraycontroller

I have two `NSArrayControllers` in my `MainWindow.xib` and want to use both of them with CoreData. Both are using entities of the same type from the same data model. These two array controllers are bound each to their own table views (one for generated data, one for stored data).

The first array controller is connected to the managed object context in `AppDelegate` but what do I do about the second array controller? It doesn't seem it can be connected to the same managed object context. If I compile now I get the error *`Cannot perform operation without a managed object context`* for the second array controller.

Comment: why can't it be connected to the same moc?

Comment: Well, at least not with the connections in IB as far as I understand, or how would you do that? Because only one target can be connected to AppDelegate.managedObjectContext and that is already connected to my first array controller.

Comment: why not bin it via the bindings inspector?

Comment: Please edit your question to include a detailed description of what happens when you try to set the second array controller's MOC. There's no reason this shouldn't work, so you may have found an Xcode bug.

Comment: The way how I bound this so far is by adding an NSObject to my xib, set its class to AppDelegate and then connect by ctrl-drag from AppDelegate.moc to the array controller (if I remember this correctly). I haven't tried this yet via the bindings inspector. I've bound the table views to the ACs via the inspector. How can I bind the ACs to the MOC via the inspector?

Comment: Wait! Say nothing! I've just figured it out! There's a property for the MOC in the inspector for the ACs. :)

Comment: Please add your answer and mark it accepted to close the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer this question on my own now:

The binding inspector in IB has bindings on NSArrayController for the Managed Object Context. I wasn't completely sure that this is the right way to bind the array controllers but it obviously seems to be so.